# Establishing queues in SimpleInjector for MassTransit on the Publisher side

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, simple-injector, masstransit

I have 2 applications, an event publishing one and an event consumer one.
The publishing one uses SimpleInjector:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(() => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitHostName"), hostConfigurator =>
        {

        });

    }));
});
```

The consumer one uses CastleWindsor:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(configurationProvider.RabbitHostName);

        x.AddConsumer<FactAddedHandler>();
        x.AddConsumer<FactAddedWebhookHandler>();
        x.AddConsumer<FactMonitorHandler>();

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(container);
    }));

});
```

What happens when I start the **consumer** application is that it creates all the queues and exchanges for the related subscribers. However, such thing doesn't happen when I start only the publishing application. Meaning that if no queues are existing and the **publisher** application starts and publishes events *before* the **consumer** application is started, those events are lost.
By following the documentation https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/simpleinjector.html
I can see that masstransit has it's own way to define consumers in simple injector, but not a way to define the publishers.
I could find this:

```
cfg.Publish<ScreeningAddedIntegrationEvent>(@event =>
{
    @event.Durable = false; // default: true
});
```

which helps me defining the way I want to publish a specific message but still doesn't create any queue or exchange behind the scene yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how MT /RMQ works. It's obviously not possible for MT to determine which events you may or may not publish based on your application flow. You should ensure your consuming service is started first, or at least that the bus topology is set up correctly, before starting services that will start publishing.